# Clojure: What does [_] do in a Functions Argument List?

Tags: syntax, vector, clojure, arguments

I am working through the joy of clojure and am wondering what the _ syntax does in a functions argument vector.

Example:

```
(def available-processors
    (.availableProcessors (Runtime/getRuntime)))

(prn "available processors: " available-processors)

(def pool
    (Executors/newFixedThreadPool (+ 2 available-processors)))

(defn dothreads!
    [func & {thread-count :threads exec-count :times :or {thread-count 1 exec-count 1}}]
    (dotimes [t thread-count]
        (.submit pool #(dotimes [_ exec-count] (func)))))
```

What is the underscore doing in the form:

```
#(dotimes [_ exec-count] (func))
```

Comment: In Haskell, the _ denotes something you don't really care about. Like a catch-all "anything". Sort of a "whatever is here" variable. Interested to see if it's similar in clojure...

Comment: https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#__code_code_unused_argument

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe that underscore is used in Clojure, by convention, as a placeholder for a required but unused argument.  As [Keith Bennet](http://krbtech.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/same-temperature-converter-different-language-clojure/) puts it:

> In Clojure, the underscore is used idiomatically to indicate that the
>   argument it identifies is not subsequently used.

Your example is consistent with this "usage," since the first argument to `dotimes`, which is an indexer, is not needed, but the binding is required by the form.

Comment: I believe this comes from haskell.

Comment: and haskell probably got it from prolog. I'm not sure where it started though.

Answer (score 13):

Nothing special about it, it is just a convention for naming something that you don't care about, but still it is a name and can be used like a normal name.

```
(defn hello [_] (+ 1 _))
(hello 10)
```

**UPDATE**

Doing this:

```
(defn hello [a a]  (+ a a))
```

doesn't produce an error and hence you can use as many _ as you want ;).

NOTE: The above isn't the case with Scheme or CL... Hmm what was the rational behind it in clojure then???

Comment: Would you distinguish between this case and the case where the symbol is actually not used anywhere but required for the signature?  That is how I understood it.  In other words, I personally haven't used `_` where it would actually be referenced.

Comment: @harpo As far as the Clojure compiler and runtime are concerned, `_` is just an ordinary symbol with no special semantics.  By convention, Clojure developers use `_` instead of something like `ignored` or `dont-care` because `_` is shorter and looks distinctive.  Of course, you are free to follow the convention or not.  I personally wouldn't use it the way Ankur's example did; in his case, the symbol is actually referenced somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are good, but since I needed some extra clarification, here's my answer.

```
(defn blah[_] (str "the value you sent is " _)
```

is identical to

```
(defn blah[my-arg] (str "the value you sent is " my-arg)
```

There is no difference. _ is just a way to let the person looking at the code to know that the parameter is not intended to be used.

So for example, this is fine programatically:

```
(dotimes [_ 5] (println (str "I'm going to print this 5 times, and this is index # " _)))
```

But someone looking at the code would think you aren't planning on using the _. So it would be better to use 'n' or 'ind' or whatever, instead of _, just to be clear. If you aren't using that value, like below...

```
(dotimes [_ 5] (println "I'm going to print this 5 times"))
```

Then it makes since to bind your parameter to _, as you are indicating that you aren't using it.

And one last thing, if bindings have the same name, the last one wins. So the following will print "4last4last4last4last".

```
(defn will-print [_ a _ a _ a _ a] (println (str _ a _ a _ a _ a)))
(will-print 1 "a" 2 "b" 3 "c" 4 "last")
```

So in the println block '_' is bound to 4, and 'a' is bound to 'last'. All of the previous values sent are ignored/overwritten.